# "I go to school at [School Name (specifically a high school)]"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you say this in German? I've been thinking about this on and off for almost 2 years and just got around to asking. My guess would be

> Ich gehe zur/in die Schule bei/an [Riverside High School]

I think my problem comes from zur vs in die, as well as what preposition to use for at. I get how to say where you study for University, but not where you go for high school/middle school etc.

Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the proper name as the noun:

```
Ich gehe auf die Riverside High School.
```

Here "auf eine Schule gehen" means to attend a school regularly.  A more formal alternative:

```
Ich besuche die Riverside High School.
```

Even if "besuchen" translates to "visit", it's meaning is attending school.